Cesium tiles to 3D format (gpkg/cityjson/obj)
I am intending to use the amazing "Rotterdam in 3D" (https://www.3drotterdam.nl/) dataset to 3d-print. I am able to load the whole tileset as scene into QGIS.
Now I would like to export an aoi as a 3d-object, preferably a gpkg to preserve coordinates, but a obj file could also work.
Is this possible with QGIS?


unfortunately, not possible.
